# jQuery function in .each() only works on last li element

Tags: jquery, each, prop

This code appends a new `li` element within a form to a list. After that, I would like to add a 'active' class to specific elements and set a 'checked' to checkboxes.

Problem: The Code works only on the last element. All previous elements are without 'active' or 'checked'.

```
var menus = $.parseJSON(product_json.menu);

$.each(menus, function (menu_key, menu_value) {

    form = add_menu_form(menu_key);
    $('#menus').append(form);


    if (menu_value.allergens === undefined) {

        $('.btn-multi-check-box').prop('checked', false);
        $('.btn-multi-check-label').removeClass('active');

    } else {

        $.each(menu_value.allergens, function (allergens_key, allergens_value) {

             $('#menu_' + menu_key + '_allergens_' + allergens_key).prop("checked", true);
             $('.btn-' + menu_key + '-allergens-' + allergens_key).addClass("active");

        });
    }

});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This line: `$('.btn-multi-check-box').prop('checked', false);` will affect every box. Nothing about that line will change from one element to the next.

Comment: Allright. But that's only in case, menu_value.allergens is undefined.

Comment: But if it is ever the case, you remove *all* checks and make *all* labels inactive.

Comment: console.log(menu_value.allergens) shows me the json Object which is not undefined.